# Do URL shorteners prevent ugly words?

Tags: url-shortener

Do you know about any URL shortener that filters out ugly bad words?

For example, when [goo.gl](http://goo.gl/) (or any other URL shortener) generates short URLs, does it skip URLs like `goo.gl/evil` or `goo.gl/YouDie` or `goo.gl/f__k` (without the two characters omitted)?

I imagine it'd be rather complicated to filter out bad words, since lots of languages use the Latin alphabet, and is it really feasible to filter out all bad words in all languages?

In my Webapp, I generate GUIDs, but include only numbers and consonants and the vovels `u` and `y` so as not to generate any bad words (or so I hope). However, Google's short URLs seem to include all vowels.

**Update:** A few weeks ago, I asked Bitly if they remove "ugly" words: they do not. I also asked on Google's URL shortener mailing list, if that URL shortener removes "ugly" words; no response so far.

Comment: What's the problem if an url sounds nasty somewhere? The page it links to probably isn't so at most some people won't click it... And how in hell is `evil` a bad/ugly word?!

Comment: I've only ever seen goo.gl URLs with 5 trailing characters in them. That said, the odds of the letters being in the right order to spell any particular word are (1/62)^5, or approximately 1.09e-7% chance of the word occurring. I don't think it's a major concern.

Comment: You should ask this question to the google shortener team or bitly team, nobody can guess, it depend on the implementation. Btw: the probability to generate a real world with a combination of alphanumeric char is very low and I guess that they will not take care of all cultures (russian, french .... words)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I think your company's name could be slightly slightly damaged by appearing close to words people tend to dislike. I personally don't think `evil` is a good or bad word but other people might consider it a bad word, or associate the URL shortener company with that word.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: What about an URL shortener that *only* generated "bad/ugly" words? Do you think that would affect your company's reputation? Does that indicate that "bad/ugly" words does matter a tiny bit after all? However, in reality, bad words might be very infrequent, not worth bothering about, as strictlyrude27 and  JohnJohnGa mentioned.

Comment: @JohnJohnGa I actually asked Bitly, they said *"Thanks for asking, and we do not filter or censor."* Perhaps I'll ask Google too, then I'll update this page.

Comment: Please don't use profanity, even when doing so may seem appropriate for an example. The problem is, people need to use SO at work, and little 'drops' like that make net nannies block the site.

Comment: @Tim Post Thank you. Good to know, also when I'm building my own sites :-)

Comment: This question was closed as off topic.  Why do you consider it being off topic?  Any suggestion on somewhere else where I ought to have asked this question? Best regards

Comment: @Tim Post  I think it is on topic actually, that it's related to programming and software development in this way:  I'm generating GUIDs in my webapp. They're visible in the URL.  Hence I wonder if I should exclude "bad" words, or perhaps it's not worth the trouble. Now, people who make URL shorteners must have thought about this. If they don't filter out "bad" words, then perhaps neither do I need to do that. -- I think this question is related to ["a specific programming problem"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), i.e. generating GUIDS.

Comment: @KajMagnus If you'd like to make some edits, I'd be happy to re-visit it.

Comment: @Tim Post: Thank you. Doesn't matter that much though :-)  I've found the answer already. (I do wonder a little bit though: in which way was it off topic -- so I can write a better question the next time)

Comment: Here's one (kinda) – note `FvcK`: https://t.co/OzNwFvcKlV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think so. Really why would they do it?
They just have to write it down in the TOS that the URL shortener uses a totally automated name generator. So every possible combination can occur.

It is much easier than writing a complicated code for that.

Comment: Why would they do it? I think that if your company's name appears close to a "bad/ugly" word, then that tend to negatively affect how people perceive your company. What if there were `goo.gl/is-evil` links everywhere, do you think that'd affect people's impression of Google?  So this could be one reason. However I'd guess it's hardly worth the time, since ugly words are fairly unlikely to appear.

Comment: Another reason could be so as not to be sued by e.g. religious fanatics, because of some unfortunate short link. But your TOS approach seems to be a much simpler & better solution to this problem.